# Both child components are firing the same event when only clicking on of them only

Tags: angular

I have 2 identical child components on the page. The child component contains a table and a series of functionality.

```
<app-child [model]="model1" (onDelete)="deleteForModel1($event)">
</app-child>

<app-child [model]="model2" (onDelete)="deleteForModel2($event)">
</app-child>
```

I have this method in the component.

```
deleteItem(id: number): void{
  if(confirm('Do you want to delete this item?')){
    //...
    this.onDelete.emit(id);
  }
}
```

Everything works fine when I click on the first child-component. However, when I click on the second component, **deleteItem** method runs **2x**.

Does Angular fail to realize that there are 2 child components?

Thanks for helping

Comment: can you reproduce it on a stackblitz example?

Comment: How is `deleteItem` wired inside the component?

Comment: @Benny, that's a good question. Actually, I am not using event binding directly. I'm using querySelector to get the element then attach the event listener to it. The reason is that I'm using a checkbox to toggle the value. The problem with the checkbox is that, once clicked, it changes it's state. That's why I'm capturing the event before it gets to the check box. That may be the issue. Let me take a look at that

Comment: @Richard77 I hope you will find out the cause. In any event (no pun intended...) it's not recommended to handle events by accessing the elements directly and bypassing Angular's mechanism.